# Can we run MVC4 application in Sitecore CMS 7.2 rev.140526 or does it require MVC5?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

I have installed visual studio 2012(supporting MVC4 and .NET 4.5) and Sitecore  CMS 7.2 rev.140526. I am able to run the Sitecore using admin user and launch the website too.

I was going through [this tutorial on MVC integration with Sitecore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3Mwcphtz4w) which creates an MVC application in visual studio and then integrates in the Sitecore CMS site. When I followed the same steps I got error. The MVC version used in this tutorial is MVC3 and the Sitecore version is 7.1.

I have tried the same in my machine but got the error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0`. From the error I understand that it is looking for MVC5 but in machine I have only MVC4.

Is there any way to resolve this?
First of all, is Sitecore 7.2 is compiled in MVC4 or MVC5?

Comment: Excerpt from the release notes of 7.2 (140228): "Sitecore 7.2 requires Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 5.1. To make installation easier, the Microsoft MVC DLLs are now distributed with Sitecore in the /bin folder." Hence, it's strange that it can't find the `System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: FWIW, you should be able to update your project using nuget `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -version 5.1.3` (which will put you inline with 7.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the Sitecore compatibility table:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

It clearly states that Sitecore 7.1 is compatible with MVC 4 but newer versions of Sitecore (7.2 and 7.5) do not support MVC 4 and they require ASP.NET MVC 5.1